# Run some automated task via Semaphore after merging a PR (github) ?

Tags: maven, github, continuous-integration

We have a maven project on github for which we use [Semaphore-CI](http://semaphoreci.com). 
Each time we merge a PR, the person who merges it is responsible for deploying a copy to [our public package repo](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/m2repo/), incrementing the version number and pushing it directly to the code repo.

I was wondering if there is a way to automate this. Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Semaphore's [custom commands](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/customizing-build-commands.html) to add the steps for pushing to this other repository.

Ex:

```
git remote add public_package http://example.com/public.git
git push --mirror public_package
```

Comment: But an issue: semaphore get's triggered in two scenarios (1) when we make changes to master (say merge a PR)  (2) someone submits a PR. We want our costume operation to run only  in the first case. How can distinguish between these two on the Semaphore side?

Comment: You can just check to make sure you're on master before running the custom script then https://rietta.com/blog/2014/02/16/get-and-compare-the-current-git-branch-in-bash/